# How to implement Notification Mechanism in windows application?

Tags: c#, api, windows-services, windows

I have a windows/ WPF application written in c#.This applications connects to remote database which is hosted in our public server.The application will install to all the systems.User can add the values to the database by this application.
I need an notification mechanism to send notifications to all the installed windows application when someone add any values to the database.

Please advice me the best approach to implement this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that directly connected to the database? NO server? SQL Server? Use message broker to notify clients that listen to messages.

Comment: I am using sql server.Database update will not occur regularly.it may occur  even after one day or two days like that.So i think timer or frequent checking from application is not an effective way.But we need to send notifications from server to client applications(Windows Applications) only when update occurred.

Comment: Never ever send notifications from a server to a client - always have the client connect. And Message Broker supports exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Query Notifications feature of SQL Server that allows applications to be notified when data has changed.

Refer the below links.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555893?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: It is what I mentioned - using the broker. Yes ,it will work as it is the client opening the connection to the server and waiting for a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Make the architecture general and interface driven, so you can swap out the underlying transport.

```
public interface INotificationService
{
    event EventHandler NewNotification;
    void SendEvent(string eventDetails);
}
```

As a really overly simple example.

The implementation, well you have a few (hundred) options. You mention that the events are being put in a database. If you ensure there is a unique, incrementing integer key you can poll the database from each client for any events > the last event ID. Do that every 10 seconds or however quickly you can get away with. It's a very minor performance hit and not that efficient, but very simple and reliable and you already have access to the database because you are putting events there.

Alternatively you can create a web service, or WCF service. A Web service would generally need to be polled, a WCF service could be configured with duplex comms so you wouldn't need to poll.

Other options include MSMQ, or one of the other messaging solutions, RabbitMQ, Tibco, what ever. It all depends on the details.

The important thing here is to make sure you have that initial interface and code to it, that way, if your database polling becomes too slow and you need to upgrade to Tibco, it's a very localised simple change.

Comment: I am using sql server.Database update will not occur regularly.it may occur even after one day or two days like that.So i think timer or frequent checking from application is not an effective way.But we need to send notifications from server to client applications(Windows Applications) only when update occurred.